# How to display 500 error view with custom message?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to display messages depending on the type of exception in my own `'errors.500'` view. I have done the following solution in `Handler` class, which so far works, but I'm afraid that this isn't quite right, because it converts server type exception into http type. May it cause any danger? What is the better approach?

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    if ($exception instanceof FatalErrorException) {
        $exception = new HttpException(500, "Server error");
    }

    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
       $exception = new HttpException(500, "Model not found");
    }

    if ($exception instanceof RelationNotFoundException) {
        $exception = new HttpException(500, "Relation not found");
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: First off, not found exceptions should have an http status code of 404. Ssecondly, why would you need a normal exception? I expect you are serving HTML over HTTP(S), so an HTML Exception should be fine? If you don't want it converted, why convert it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant http, my mistake. The `ModelNotFoundException` is the Eloquent exception, on the server side. Laravel doesn't render exceptions that are not `HttpException` instances, that's why I converted it.

Comment: See my answer below. Yeah you should be fine using these

Answer (score 1):

Showing the exception is a good idea in dev mode. It is especially helpful for programmers to be able to see the exception at runtime, however your users in general will not understand much when an Exception is shown to them and the very few users who understand them might use it against you.

In my opinion the best approach is to show the exception to trusted developers and a general purpose error page/view/popup/screen to users in general, so, convert the problem into an exception only for your crew and convert the problem into friendly text in the case of users.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just so you can set the correct status code?

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof FatalErrorException) {
        $code = 500;
    }

    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
       $code = 404;
    }

    if ($exception instanceof RelationNotFoundException) {
        $code = 404;
    }
    $exception = new HttpException($exception->getMessage(), $code, $exception->getFile(), $exception->getLine());
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```